# Transform object with gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, transform, gravity

I am having a problem with gravity VS transform position.

I have an object falling down but I would like to change its position while it falls. But as soon as I attach a transform position in a script to the gameobject, gravity stops working.

Here is how I attend to make it moving (pos.x/pos.y are variables) in C#:

```
pointer.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-pos.x-280, pos.y-50, 252);
```

Comment: Maybe change the transform on the rigid body?

Comment: Changing the position once should not stop it from falling or stop it from accelerating due to gravity. If you keep changing the position every update, then you will see only tiny fleeting effects of gravity and the velocity in the fixed updates.

Comment: Yes Douglas makes a good point - are you _constantly_ changing the position or is it a one-off?

Comment: I am constantly changing it.

Comment: Yes @DouglasZare, this is exactly what is happening, I keep changing the position in the Update(). I only see tiny fleeting effect of gravity as you said. How can I fix this? Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Where in the script do you place that line of code?
If you are placing it inside the Update() function you would be setting the position to be Vector3(-pos.x-280, pos.y-50, 252) in each frame!

Comment: Yes, I placed it in the Update() function. I still don't get how to make it work. Also, I forgot to say that the gravity is on the Parent gameobject and I am trying to transform the position of its child. When I run my script, the child is moving well but the gravity is changing the parent position very very slowly. Why?

Comment: I guess by gravity you mean the physics engine gravity, which affects any rigidbody which is not kinematic (i mena the field "is kinematic" is not enabled). If the parent object has a rigidbody the child object will be affected, indirectly, by gravity, even if it "is kinematic".
I would suggest you update the child object separatedly.
are you using the parenting for something else than controlling the relative position between objects?